# How to download files directly from amazon s3?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, laravel-5

This is my file uploading function:

```
$file = $req->file('upload_file');
$name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$fileName = time() . rand(1, 10000) . '_' . $name;
if($file) {
  $storage = \Storage::disk('s3')->put($fileName, file_get_contents($file), 'public');
}
if ($storage) {
  $savePdf = Pdf_exports::create(
    [
      'pdf_name' => $fileName,
    ]
  );
}
```

I'm using jQuery DataTables to list the files. I'm creating the download links like so:

```
 $('td:eq(6)', nRow).html('<div class="actionGrp"><a href="' + URL_general + '/dowlnoadPdf?id=' + aData.id + '" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Download"><span class="fa fa-download"></span></a></div>').addClass('txt-center');
```

How can I download the PDF directly when clicking the the download button?

Answer (score 0):

**Finally i got the Answer**

```
return Storage::disk('s3')->download($pdf_name);
```